# QCheckBox stateChanged not triggered reliably

Tags: python, qt

Here is a Qt riddle: PythonQt. Win10. Within Slicer 3d (I am hoping, that this is not the issue).

- Defined a QCheckBox in the QtDesigner.
- Said: `ui.checkBox.connect('stateChanged(int)', _on_checkBox)`

The callback:

```py
def _on_checkbox(val: int):
  print(f"Value: {val}.")
  ui.checkBox.setValue(0)
```

**Expected**: Either an endless loop, forever setting that checkbox to False, or
(hoped-for) a behavior that simply enforces False *(not my ultimate use-case.
This is just research-code, trying to understand checkboxes)*.

Instead I observe:

a.: Starting out at state `0` (not checked). Click!

b.: Callback is triggered: `Value: 2.`, checkbox remains unchecked. Click!

c.: **Callback is *not* triggered, checkbox turns checked!** Click! -> Back to (a), triggering the callback, printing `Value: 0.`.

Are there two distinct checkstate properties to such a checkbox? So, that the `checkBox.setValue(0)`
does not reset the 2 that has been received in (b), leading to setting it to
2 for (c) is not a state change, thus omitting the callback?

And the core question, **how do I get to my desired behavior: A callback that
is triggered every time a user clicks on the checkbox while it is enabled?**

Comment: I don't know PyQt well, but with standard Qt in C++ you actually don't have a setValue() method for the checkbox, you have setChecked() (accepting a bool) and setCheckState (accepting a Qt::CheckState). Maybe just try `ui.checkBox.setChecked(false)`? However, that'll likely cause and endless loop, so you'll need to block signals for the checkbox, i.e. use `with QSignalBlocker(ui.checkBox) as blocker:` before calling `setChecked()`. Also, if you don't care about tri-state, you might want to look at the `toggled(bool)` signal instead of `stateChanged(int)`, though that shouldn't matter here.

Comment: Thanks for your response, AFAIK the difference between setValue and setChecked is in fact, that the former supports int tristate and the latter is boolean check/nocheck. Yes, an endless loop would have been my expectation, too. However, I observed what I described in my post.

Comment: No, `setCheckState()` is for supporting tristate, `setValue()` doesn't exist, at least not in the C++ version of Qt. My guess is that you calling a non-existent method causes a Python exception to be raised that'll get eaten because it was called from within the event handler logic of Qt.

Comment: chris_se. Thanks. Yes, that may be, that the Python interface offers a function here, that is really not there. This page supports your theory, showing the complete, inherited, official interface, and lo: There is no `setValue(..)`: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcheckbox-members.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be calling `setChecked()` instead of that non-existing method `setValue()`.
Calling an event(signal) handler endlessly is a bad behavior and most UI frameworks including Qt avoid that. See [the implementation](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/v6.4.2/src/widgets/widgets/qcheckbox.cpp#L227) for detail.

It's not a good idea to pair the `stateChanged` signal of the `QCheckBox` with the `setChecked()` method of the base class(`QAbstractButton`). Rather, you should pair it with the `setCheckState()` method.(You can pair the `toggled` signal with the `setChecked()` method.)

For a signal emitted every time a user clicks, use the `clicked` signal.

See the following example.

```
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *

app = QApplication()

c = QCheckBox('test')
c.clicked.connect(lambda: print('clicked'))

def on_change(v):
    print('on_change, v:', v)
    c.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
c.stateChanged.connect(on_change)

c.show()

app.exec()
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Had not been aware of that "setCheckState" function, and assumed that I need "setValue" for supporting tristate. So I take as an answer: "Using SetValue (exists, at least I get no error and my example works as described) leads to bad behavior and should be avoided."

Comment: Weeks later, reading this manual: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcheckbox-members.html , seeing that there indeed is no `setValue(..)`, at least in the real interface that is merely being wrapped by Python, I fully accept your answer. Thanks again!